# How to rename a file by removing a string from the filename?

Tags: linux, shell

I have several files that I would like to rename. The files look like this :

1. `File_2hvrU9QO4smHicntISuaXY63JgYNLd9VRrXqX.part1.rar`
2. `File_2SjyV2S2lH3l6BLMSrfeKzjIcMvnvbXbEgmxZ.part2.rar`

Is there a way to remove the middle part in order to get something like:
`File.part1.rar`?

Or maybe a way to extract them as they are ?

Comment: Do all files start as `File_` ? And you would need part1.rar and part2.rar, right ?

Comment: Yes they all start with File and yes I do need the part1.rar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work.

```
for name in File_*.part*
  do
    new_name=$(echo "${name}" | sed -e 's|\(File\)_.*\(\.part.*\)|\1\2|g')
    echo "Renaming ${name} file to ${new_name}"
    mv "${name}" "${new_name}"
  done
```

Do test it first with a copy of some of the files to a temporary location.

**Notes**:

- This will not work if the name contains `|`
- If there are name collisions, this will ask for confirmation

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly.
I'm new to shell and I didn't know the sed command could you please explain

 's|\(File\)_.*\(\.part.*\)|\1\2|g'` 

I get that you're replacing the string but the last part i.e. |\1\2|g'` not so much

Comment: Sure. BTW, there is a typo in your comment, you have missed the `\(..\)'`around the `File`. We are matching the regex and collecting the desired patterns in `\(..\)`. The `\1 and \2`  will then retain the matched patterns, in that order, while substituting. Have a look here https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4 to understand